# Complex Json parsing: key not found but seems there yet

Tags: python, json

I have this "very nested" Json: https://textdoc.co/iWgRduZxl2JEkXU1 that i have to get through a webservice (no issue there) and then operate with Python (issue there).

I have used this online tools to create the python class from the (validated) json file: https://json2csharp.com/code-converters/json-to-python

So, here's what i have so far (after light corrections: declarations were weirdly ordered):

```
@dataclass
class DocDiffCheck:
    data_name_description: str
    data_name_in_script: str
    data_value: object

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(obj: Any) -> 'DocDiffCheck':
        _data_name_description = str(obj.get("data_name_description"))
        _data_name_in_script = str(obj.get("data_name_in_script"))
        _data_value = str(obj.get("data_value"))
        return DocDiffCheck(_data_name_description, _data_name_in_script, _data_value)

@dataclass
class DataValue:
    hashtag_value: str
    hashtag_description: str
    hashtag_descripteurs: str
    hashtag_dat_collect_start: str
    hashtag_dat_collect_end: str

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(obj: Any) -> 'DataValue':
        _hashtag_value = str(obj.get("hashtag_value"))
        _hashtag_description = str(obj.get("hashtag_description"))
        _hashtag_descripteurs = str(obj.get("hashtag_descripteurs"))
        _hashtag_dat_collect_start = str(obj.get("hashtag_dat_collect_start"))
        _hashtag_dat_collect_end = str(obj.get("hashtag_dat_collect_end"))
        return DataValue(_hashtag_value, _hashtag_description, _hashtag_descripteurs, _hashtag_dat_collect_start, _hashtag_dat_collect_end)

@dataclass
class EndsIn30:
    data_name_in_script: str
    data_name_description: str
    data_value: List[DataValue]

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(obj: Any) -> 'EndsIn30':
        _data_name_in_script = str(obj.get("data_name_in_script"))
        _data_name_description = str(obj.get("data_name_description"))
        _data_value = [DataValue.from_dict(y) for y in obj.get("data_value")]
        return EndsIn30(_data_name_in_script, _data_name_description, _data_value)

@dataclass
class GlobalDbStat:
    Type: str
    TotalCount: int
    CrawledCount: int

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(obj: Any) -> 'GlobalDbStat':
        _Type = str(obj.get("Type"))
        _TotalCount = int(obj.get("TotalCount"))
        _CrawledCount = int(obj.get("CrawledCount"))
        return GlobalDbStat(_Type, _TotalCount, _CrawledCount)

@dataclass
class VolumétrieCategorie:
    Categorie: str
    Total: int
    Crawled: int

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(obj: Any) -> 'VolumétrieCategorie':
        _Categorie = str(obj.get("Categorie"))
        _Total = int(obj.get("Total"))
        _Crawled = int(obj.get("Crawled"))
        return VolumétrieCategorie(_Categorie, _Total, _Crawled)

@dataclass
class Hashtag:
    VolumétrieCategorie: List[VolumétrieCategorie]
    EndsIn30: List[EndsIn30]

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(obj: Any) -> 'Hashtag':
        _VolumétrieCategorie = [VolumétrieCategorie.from_dict(y) for y in obj.get("VolumétrieCategorie")]
        _EndsIn30 = [EndsIn30.from_dict(y) for y in obj.get("EndsIn30")]
        return Hashtag(_VolumétrieCategorie, _EndsIn30)

@dataclass
class Website:
    CorpusName: str
    TotalCount: int
    CrawlCount: int

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(obj: Any) -> 'Website':
        _CorpusName = str(obj.get("CorpusName"))
        _TotalCount = int(obj.get("TotalCount"))
        _CrawlCount = int(obj.get("CrawlCount"))

@dataclass
class RSN:
    Type: str
    TotalCount: int
    CrawlCount: int

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(obj: Any) -> 'RSN':
        _Type = str(obj.get("Type"))
        _TotalCount = int(obj.get("TotalCount"))
        _CrawlCount = int(obj.get("CrawlCount"))
        return RSN(_Type, _TotalCount, _CrawlCount)

@dataclass
class UGC:
    Plateforme: str
    TotalCount: int
    CrawlCount: int

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(obj: Any) -> 'UGC':
        _Plateforme = str(obj.get("Plateforme"))
        _TotalCount = int(obj.get("TotalCount"))
        _CrawlCount = int(obj.get("CrawlCount"))
        return UGC(_Plateforme, _TotalCount, _CrawlCount)
        return Website(_CorpusName, _TotalCount, _CrawlCount)

@dataclass
class Root:
    global_db_stats: List[GlobalDbStat]
    Hashtags: List[Hashtag]
    Websites: List[Website]
    UGC: List[UGC]
    RSN: List[RSN]
    Doc_Diff_Check: List[DocDiffCheck]

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(obj: Any) -> 'Root':
        _global_db_stats = [GlobalDbStat.from_dict(y) for y in obj.get("global_db_stats")]
        _Hashtags = [Hashtag.from_dict(y) for y in obj.get("Hashtags")]
        _Websites = [Website.from_dict(y) for y in obj.get("Websites")]
        _UGC = [UGC.from_dict(y) for y in obj.get("UGC")]
        _RSN = [RSN.from_dict(y) for y in obj.get("RSN")]
        _Doc_Diff_Check = [DocDiffCheck.from_dict(y) for y in obj.get("Doc_Diff_Check")]
        return Root(_global_db_stats, _Hashtags, _Websites, _UGC, _RSN, _Doc_Diff_Check)
```

Then i used this code to get the json:

```
json_api_response = json.loads(strApiResponse)
my_json = Root.from_dict(json_api_response)
```

I have this exception:

```
File "XXXX.py", line 210, in MODULE_NAME
    return Root.from_dict(json_api_response)
    File "XXXX.py", line 168, in from_dict
    _Hashtags = [Hashtag.from_dict(y) for y in obj.get("Hashtags")]
    File "XXXX.py", line 168, in <listcomp>
    _Hashtags = [Hashtag.from_dict(y) for y in obj.get("Hashtags")]
    File "XXXX.py", line 114, in from_dict
    _EndsIn30 = [EndsIn30.from_dict(y) for y in obj.get("EndsIn30")]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I know that it means that the key "Hashtags" is not found but i don't get why.

Comment: "hashtags" or "Hashtags" ? You are using uppercase in your code.

Comment: Typo corrected.

Comment: So from your error -- it seems that `obj.get("EndsIn30")` is producing a `None` response which cannot be iterated, so you may want to either check before looping through the content that either there is a key or that the value is an iterable.

Comment: Ok but...i didn't loop through anything considering that the exception happened with ```my_json = Root.from_dict(json_api_response)```

Comment: use dacite https://github.com/konradhalas/dacite

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue came from the json structure.
I changed it to avoid "nested" structure where the issue was located (EndsIn30)

Then I changes the classes and everything went well.

So, problem solved but problem's origin still unknown.